# Do NOT log "File does not exist" errors. How to?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have millions of "File does not exist" errors each month in logs of my flash game website. Flash files call those unexisted files.

There are over 10000 different unexisted files in many variety of directories, extensions and referrers.

I want "File does not exist" errors to be not logged. Can't figure out a way to do it. Can you help me? I don't want to use htaccess.

Using php, mysql, apache, Linux, os_CentOS 5

Comment: You should try to find the cause for all this log messages. Why are your flash files trying to access nonexistent files?

Comment: It is not possible. Because there are over 10000 flash game files with over 500 different types of required files, score tables, images, videos, images etc.. Check y8.com to get the point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a logging daemon such as [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng) or [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) and have it drop lines that match certain patterns such as "File does not exist".

To get Apache to use syslog, you can change your logging directives to something like these:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t 'apache'" combined
ErrorLog syslog
```

Comment: Would this cause to a slowness in sites? I get around 1M page view/day. To give an idea, my current system can handle barely 2M page view/day.

Comment: I have never tried to benchmark the overhead of using syslog rather than writing directly to files but I currently run a syslog-ng server that logs 3M hits per day just for the web tier (and it logs everything from logins to mail as well) without struggling in the slightest.  My guess is that lower disk utilisation due to not logging the error messages will actually make your site faster.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your solution and let you know the results.